# Changing return type of methods base class

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have a class called ProgramE that a subclass of DataAccess. How would I be able to make a generic method that returns a type of the calling class?

This is the code in the DataAccess class.

```
    public MongoCursor<DataAccess> GetAll(QueryComplete query)
    {
        MongoServer server = MongoServer.Create(C.connectionString);
        MongoDatabase db = server.GetDatabase(C.database);
        MongoCollection<DataAccess> collection = db.GetCollection<DataAccess>(_collectionName);
        var result = collection.FindAs<DataAccess>(query);

        return result;
    }
```

Here is what I am trying to do. I get this error. "Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List'"

```
        ProgramE p = new ProgramE();
        QueryComplete query = Query.EQ("InstalledOn.SystemID", audit.SystemID);

        List<ProgramE> ServerPrograms = p.GetAll(query).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Would something like that work for you?

```
public MongoCursor<T> GetAll<T>(QueryComplete query) where T : DataAccess {
    MongoServer server = MongoServer.Create(C.connectionString);
    MongoDatabase db = server.GetDatabase(C.database);
    MongoCollection<T> collection = db.GetCollection<T>(_collectionName);
    return collection.FindAs<T>(query);
}

List<ProgramE> ServerPrograms = p.GetAll<ProgramE>(query).ToList();
```

Comment: That does accomplish what I would need to do but is there anyway to do it without having to do something like "p.GetAll<ProgramE>" and using p.GetAll instead?